# How do I setup and use std::map<void*, MyClass*>

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a program with a set of input and a set of out variables that I exchange with an Apache/PHP webpage using XML. The webpage is where users can see what is configured/going on and can change settings.

When I pass the XML to the PHP program (we use Unix_domain Sockets) I add a lot of meta-information about the settings and indicators I'm passing to him.  Things like datatype, min, max, default, read/write privileges, etc.

```
<temperature datatype="INT32" min=-"40" max="150" permissions="R/O">25</temperature>
```

I need to know the metadata about each of my variables as I build the outbound xml.  I though a good way to do this wouldbe to create a class VarInfo which I'd associate to each variable.  Insted of storing the variable name as the key in the map (not sure I can always know the variable name) I thought of making the key be the pointer to the variable and the value be the pointer to a VarInfo object for that variable.  Only way I know to store mixed pointer types is to cast them all to void*.  So, something like:

```
bool cmpr( void* a, void*b) { return (long)a < (long)b;};
std::map<void*,VarInfo*,cmpr>   VarMap;

int        temperature;
VarInfo    vi_temperature;

VarMap[(void*)&temperature] = &vi_temperature;
```

Doing this create a bunch of errors about declaring the map.

```
expected a type, got ‘cmpr’ ACT_iod.cpp
Invalid template arguments  ACT_iod.cpp line 40 Semantic Error
invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for 
    ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map’
```

So, can someone suggest how I might get this working and probably also suggest a better way to store the metainfo?  Still thinking about changing to std::string's as the key.

Thanks.

Comment: I _think_ you just need to change your `compr` to a `functor` object (that overrides `operator()`) for your types.  That's not encouraging or discouraging the overall approach, as I haven't thought that much about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third parameter of the `std::map` should be the type of the comparator. As one fix you could make `cmpr` a functor (which is often the preferred aproach due to its inlinablility):

```
struct cmpr {
  bool operator()(void* a, void* b) {...}
}
std::map<void*,VarInfo*,cmpr>   VarMap;
```

The other alternative is to use the type of the function pointer (`bool(*)(void*, void*)` iirc) and give the pointer to the actually used function as a parameter of the constructor:

```
bool cmpr( void* a, void*b) { return (intptr_t)a < (intptr_t)b;}
std::map<void*,VarInfo*,bool(*)(void*, void*)>   VarMap(&cmpr);
```

Edit: now that I think about it: The default comparison for pointers is `<` anyways, so you could just use `std::map<void*, VarInfo*>` which has the benefit of being more portable. Generally you should avoid casting pointers to `long`. Avoid pointer to integral casts when possible, otherwise using `intptr_t`, `uintptr_t` or `size_t` is a much better idea, since `long` is not guaranteed to be big enough to hold a pointer (and long is indeed 32bit on some 64bit platforms).

Comment: and Chad - after reading a bit on functors (now that I know what to call them!) I see what you're talking about.  Chad, in particular, thanks for the function pointer example that explains their mention in other places but always without an example!  Any thoughts on my method for associating meta-info?

Comment: @WesMiller: I haven't commented on your way of storing meta-info, since its hard to evaluate other options without knowing your code.